# Platform-independent text-to-speech Python library to run on Windows, Linux and Mac?

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos, text-to-speech

Does anyone know if there is a Python library for text-to-speech that works on Windows, Mac and Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pyttsx](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx).

Comment: I've installed and followed the tutorial from their website. Is there a way to improve the sound quality of the synthesis? Do I have other options beside pyttsx? I'm looking for something similar to freetts project.

Comment: @Seitaridis I think that this is about it for cross platform Python TTS libraries